# ExecutorService InvokeAll Progress Bar

Tags: java, concurrency

I have an ExectorService and the following code, everything is working fine with the futures and the concurrency.  However, when I try to update my progress bar from SomeClass(), it seems to only update the UI after the invokeAll() is complete...basically the progress bar only updates once everything is complete which deems it useless.

How can I resolve this?  I've looked at CompletionServices as well as SwingWorkers but I don't know how to apply them to my code.  Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
class SomeClass() {
  private static class Result {
    private final String someVar;

    public Result(String code) {
        this.someVar = code;
    }
  }

 public static Result compute(Object obj) {
   // ... compute stuff
   someVar = "computedResult";
   return Result(someVar);
 }
 public someFunction() {
    List<Callable<Result>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Result>>();
    for (Object f : listOfObjects) {
        Callable<Result> c = new Callable<Result>() {
            @Override
            public Result call() throws Exception {
                someClassUI.jProgressBar.setValue(50);
                return compute(file);
            }
        };
        tasks.add(c); 
    }

    List<Callable<Result>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Result>>();
    List<Future<Result>> results = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);

    for (Future<Result> fr : results) {
     String value = fr.get().resultValue;
    }
  }
}

class SomeClassUI {
  public static jProgressBar;

  public someClassUI() {
    jProgressBar = new JProgressBar(0,100);
  }

  private void button1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    SomeClass theClass = new SomeClass();
    theClass.someFunction();
  }

}
```

**edit**: edited to add some extra code to help understanding

Comment: You haven't shown how and where you update the progress bar. Post an SSCCE. At the moment, the code doesn't make much sense. You don't even have a task in your list.

Comment: @JB Nizet - that's actually part of my question.  I tried in multiple places, and all of them work the same way (the progress bar gets updated once everything is complete)

Comment: Then show us what you tried, so that we can explain why it behaves like this, and how to fix it.

Comment: @Sev At first glance, I think it should be updated just after `String value = fr.get().resultValue;`. The trick would be to provide an interface, or something of the sorts, for `SomeClass` to call the update on, such as `SomeClassUpdateListener`.

Comment: @JB Nizet: is this better?

Comment: @afsantos: i also tried it there, no luck -- how can i add a listener to this code?  can you show an example

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing a Swing component from a thread other than the event dispatch thread. That is forbidden by the [Swing threading policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading).

Use this code to update the progress bar from the background thread:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        someClassUI.jProgressBar.setValue(50);
    }
});
```

Read more about concurrency in swing in the [official swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: thank you -- which point in my code would you call that? within call() ?

Comment: Where you currently have `someClassUI.jProgressBar.setValue(50);`.

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately.  Still updates only when everything is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing with code similar to yours, until I realized the following:

```
<T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
                      throws InterruptedException
```

> [Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

That *"when all complete"* is what is causing the behaviour of the progress bar. In other words, if you get the list of `Future` only when all tasks complete, then, obviously, iterating over them and updating the bar would be so fast that you see only the last update, when the bar is full.

What you could do, like I did, is calling `submit` for each of your tasks, and add the `Future`s individually to a list.

---

The example code below has been tested, and works here. You should be able to adapt it to your own purposes.

**Listener interface:**

```
public interface UpdateListener {
    void update(double percent);
}
```

**Task Executor:**

```
public class SomeClass {
    // instance variables
    private UpdateListener listener;
    private ExecutorService executor;

    /** Parameter constructor of objects of class SomeClass. */
    public SomeClass(UpdateListener l) {
        listener = l;
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    }

    /** */
    public void doIt() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        int numOfTasks = 5, completedTasks = 0;

        List<Future<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<>();

        // Submit each of your tasks. Here I create them manually.
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfTasks; ++i) {
            final int I = i;
            Callable<Integer> c = new Callable<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep((long) I * 1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return new Integer(I);
                }
            };
            results.add(executor.submit(c)); 
        }

        // Retrieve individual results and update progress bar.
        for (Future<Integer> fr : results) {
            Integer i = fr.get();
            ++completedTasks;
            listener.update((double) completedTasks / numOfTasks);
        }
    }
}
```

**UI class:**

```
public class SomeClassUI implements Runnable, UpdateListener {
    // instance variables
    private JProgressBar bar;
    private JFrame frame;
    private SomeClass t;

    /** Empty constructor of objects of class SomeClassUI. */
    public SomeClassUI() {
        t = new SomeClass(this);
    }

    /** Builds the interface. */
    public void run() {
        bar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        bar.setStringPainted(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        panel.add(bar);

        frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /** Method from the interface. Updates the progress bar. */
    @Overrides
    public void update(double percent) {
        final double PERCENT = percent;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int v = (int) (100 * PERCENT);
                bar.setValue(v);
            }
        });
    }

    /** Tests the program. */
    public void go() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);
        try {
            t.doIt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main() {
        new SomeClassUI().go();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi afsantos: hmm..interesting, so how would you invoke the tasks concurrently if you were to use another method other than invokeAll() ?

Comment: @Sev I've added further explanation and sample code in my answer.

Comment: This only works because the sleeps are growing. If you start with the first Callable sleeping longest, you'll find that the first time you call `fr.get()` will take that long sleep time, and the other 3 in the thread pool will be done already. You can't call the blocking `fr.get()` and still hope to get a nice smooth high-resolution progress bar...